# Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected (22,1) (UNITY)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please fix my script, something is wrong! I get this error, and I don't know what's wrong! There's something wrong at the 22nd line.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using UnityEngine;

public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public float health = 50f;


    public void TakeDamage (float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: Assets\Target.cs(22,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Comment: @Rocketman Dan Assets\Target.cs(22,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Comment: Have to agree with SleepSheepy. Normally this is caused by the wrong number of brackets but I can't see a reason this would happen there. The lines around that line look fine if I copy it over to my editor. You could try deleting and retyping the offending line, or pasting into an identical file. It can sometimes happen when there is an unexpected invisible character (copy from PDF can do this) too. I can't help you any more than to say basically try turning it off and on again by retyping the offending section.

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

Easiest things to check:

- This error comes up a lot when you've accidentally put the wrong number of closing curly braces. However I didn't see any problems in the code you posted.
- Double check that there are no extra curly braces or text at the very end of your file.

It's possible that even though you wrote `using UnityEngine;` , your code editor is bugging out and failing to recognize it. VSCode has been particularly finicky for me lately in similar ways. Here are some things you can try:

- Instead of `Destroy(gameObject);` try putting `UnityEngine.GameObject.Destroy(gameObject);` This will force the compiler to use the right namespace for that function.
- If that doesn't help, you may need to reset some things: Try creating your Target file again and copying the code over to the new file. **EDIT:** Rocketman Dan pointed out that you may need to manually retype some of the code, because there may be problems with invisible characters.
- You may also need to close your project in your code editor and re-open it. You may also need to restart Unity.
- If you use Visual Studio Code, make sure IntelliSense is working correctly.